# Part of Python code Cannot be Imported from another file

Tags: python, import

I have two python files under the same directory. One is called `a.py` and the other is called `aa.py`. They both import something from each other like:

```
# a.py
x = 1
from aa import var
y=1
```

```
# aa.py
import a
var = 1
print(a.x)
print(a.y)
```

If I run `python aa.py` It will pop up error `AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'y'`.
I am very confused why `x` is successfully imported while `y` cannot. It feels like because in `a.py`, `x` is declared before `from aa import var` but why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: You are facing a circular import. Don't do that. You must figure out a way of having imports acyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Someone with a lot more back-end programming experience could probably add a lot more, but my thought is that any Python being imported is going to be compiled *before* you can call it, and it's going to note the call for `a` before it has been defined.

FYI, you're going to run into circular dependencies if you keep writing your code like this: https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports

If you need something in both files, put it in a third file that can be called from both but that doesn't call either of the first two.

Comment: Thanks. This 'Python being imported is going to be compiled before you can call it, and it's going to note the call for a before it has been defined.'  makes sense. I know it is circular import but just curious on why.